# "Bridge" host-only adapter and NAT adapter in a VM for other VMs?

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I'm running [Foreman](https://theforeman.org) locally in a VirtualBox machine with a NAT adapter and a host-only adapter. I'm running another virtual machine locally which is bound to the same host-only adapter. I can get the second virtual machine to PXE boot, but when using the Foreman host's IP as the default gateway, I can't reach internet from the PXE host.

The Foreman host's IP address is 10.127.127.127 and the PXE machine uses this IP as its default gateway. All services on the Foreman box are accessible to the PXE machine, I can resolve DNS and all things seem to work just fine. I just can't get out to public internet from the PXE box. I've confirmed this is not a DNS issue, as I cannot curl IP addresses directly either.

Is there special configuration I need to do on the Foreman box itself to allow traffic from the `vboxnetN` adapter to be NAT'd out via the NAT adapter?

Foreman output of `ip route show`:

```
default via 10.0.2.2 dev enp0s3  proto static  metric 100
10.0.2.0/24 dev enp0s3  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.2.15  metric 100
10.127.127.0/24 dev enp0s8  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.127.127.127
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp0s8  scope link  metric 1003
```

PXE host output of `ip route show`:

```
default via 10.127.127.127 dev enp0s3
10.127.127.0/24 dev enp0s3 proto kernel scope link src 10.127.127.3
```

I have added `GATEWAY=10.0.2.2` to `/etc/sysconfig/network`. Do I need to bridge these adapters or do anything else to allow traffic from the host-only adapter to flow out through the NAT?

Comment: I'm trying to construct a routing rule for that specific adapter to route out using the default gateway. I think I'm on the right track.